# how can I save a content of a canvas drawn by a user?

Tags: c#, serialization, windows-8, deserialization

I'm having the following problem:

I'm trying to save a content of an application. The content are drawn on a canvas via users.
Example:

a user might click on a button to draw an ellipse, etc.

after clicking the button, the drawing will be displayed on a canvas.

I want to save the content drawn by the user on the canvas. Anyone could give me a hint.
Is it good if I use the serialization and deserialization?

the code is written in C# using visual studio 2012, windows 8 app

Comment: You can use javascript to convert canvas to image.

Comment: Thats what serialization for

Comment: But what I want is that, the information saved should be opened on my application, so he can modify them.

Comment: I creates a class named ObjectSerialize.cs it contains the following:

Comment: Using [Memento](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternMemento.aspx) design pattern will help...

Comment: thank you I'll check it, just another question, my canvas drawing are inside the main page, so should I create a class for save?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways of solving this:

1. Save each action of the user - just like an undo/redo stack. Very flexible but files can get very big. In this case you'd serialize a stack of commands. To load the command would have to be replayed.
2. Save the logical construction of the drawing - just like Html or SVG. No undo/redo support but smaller files. In this case you'd serialize a document model.
3. Save each resulting bitmap after an action - easier to implement than 1. and 2. but harder to support editing of elements. No serialization of .NET objects just a lot of bitmaps.

Each approach has its advantages and disadvantages.